# Can I use more than one email template files for User Registration functionality?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, templates

I have implemented a "User Registration" functionality using "CreateUserWizard" control in ASP.NET C#. When user is registered successfully, he receives an email. I used template file which reflects username and password along with redirected URL. As below:
http://myinternaldomain.xyz.com?changepassword.aspx?uname=abc&pwd=blahblah

Now, my issue is - the application should be accessible from outside domain firewall too. and external URL is something like http://myexternaldomain.xyz.com?changepassword.aspx?uname=abc&pwd=blahblah

Now, I have one template file and two URLs.

I am trying to develop a workaround to create another template file containing my external domain URL. But as of now there is no luck.

Can anybody advise is there any way to provide such template file so that both users (either internal or external) will get to see email with the respective URL?

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you need one "universal" domain, because even if you can detect if current request was local or remote (outside domain firewall) and use one of two your templates later your url will be incorrect if user will change his/her location. So I would use myexternaldomain.xyz.com and just resolve it to your local webserver IP from your local network. If you have domain firewall then you probably have local DNS server. Or maybe there is way you can setup firewall rule so your traffic for myexternaldomain.xyz.com will be transferred to your local server, I'm not sure. Both tasks are administration-related though.